# how important the space between tag and class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I read corresponding part of http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html but can't find clear note that space between dot-class and tag change meaning. According to spec `tag.clazz` is equivalent to `tag[class~="clazz"]`, and I expect that `tag .clazz` is equivalent to `tag *.clazz`. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**5.2 - Selector syntax**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#selector-syntax)
>
> A *simple selector* is either a [type selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#type-selectors) or [universal
>   selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#universal-selector) followed immediately by zero or more [attribute
>   selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors), [ID selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#id-selectors), or [pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-classes), in any
>   order. The simple selector matches if all of its components match.
>
> <sup>Note: the terminology used here in CSS 2.1 is different from what
>   is used in CSS3.</sup>
>
> A *selector* is a chain of one or more simple selectors separated by
>   combinators. Combinators are: white space, ">", and "+". White space
>   may appear between a combinator and the simple selectors around it.

So a space between a type selector and a class selector is a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

Answer (score 2):

> I expect that `tag .class` is equivalent to `tag *.clazz`. Is that true?

No. This is because `class` and `clazz` is not the same.

However, if you meant `tag .clazz` and `tag *.clazz`, then yes.

Explanation:

- `tag .clazz` means any element with the class `clazz` somewhere
  inside a tag `tag`.
- `tag *.clazz` means any element of any tag name (`*`) with the class `clazz` somewhere inside a tag `tag`.

…which is effectively identical. The space essentially means “somewhere inside”.

Comment: Thanks for answer, sorry for typo in question... +1